# The set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ is compact iff every sequence $\{ z_n \} \subset \Omega$ has a subsequence that converges to a point in $\Omega$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, complex-analysis, compactness

My textbook *Complex Analysis* by Stein and Shakarchi presents the following theorem:

> The set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ is compact if and only if every sequence $\{ z_n \} \subset \Omega$ has a subsequence that converges to a point in $\Omega$.

After many hours of unsuccessfully trying to prove this, I found the following proof [here](http://www.u.arizona.edu/%7Emwalker/econ519/Econ519LectureNotes/Bolzano-Weierstrass.pdf):

> Every sequence in a closed and bounded subset is bounded, so it has a convergent subsequence, which converges to a point in the set, because the set is closed.
>
> Conversely, every bounded sequence is in a closed and bounded set, so it has a convergent subsequence.

The problem is that I don't see how it is possible to conceive of the same proof using only the information my textbook had given me:

> The interior of $\Omega$ consists of all its interior points. Finally, a set $\Omega$ is open if every point in that set is an interior point of $\Omega$.
>
> A set is **closed** if its complement $\Omega^c = \mathbb{C} - \Omega$ is open. This property can be reformulated in terms of limit points. A point $z \in \mathbb{C}$ is said to be a **limit point** of the set $\Omega$ if there exists a sequence of points $z_n \in \Omega$ such that $z_n \not= z$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} z_n = z$. The reader can now check that a set is closed if and only if it contains all its limit points. The **closure** of any set $\Omega$ is the union of $\Omega$ and its limit points, and is often denoted by $\bar{\Omega}$.
>
> Finally, the **boundary** of a set $\Omega$ is equal to its closure minus its interior, and is often denoted by $\partial \Omega$.
>
> A set $\Omega$ is **bounded** if there exists $M > 0$ such that $|z| < M$ whenever $z \in \Omega$. In other words, the set $\Omega$ is contained in some large disc. If $\Omega$ is bounded, we define its diameter by
>
> $$\text{diam}(\Omega) = \sup_{z, w \in \Omega} |z - w|.$$
>
> A set $\Omega$ is said to be **compact** if it is closed and bounded.

Using this information, and despite many hours of effort, I was unable to prove the aforementioned theorem. Keep in mind that I have just begun learning complex analysis, so the information in this textbook is the full extent of my understanding.

I was wondering if someone could please show me how the aforementioned theorem could be proved using the information from my textbook. Or is the information in my textbook insufficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\Omega$ be a compact set and let $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of elements of $\Omega$. Since $\Omega$ is bounded, the sequence $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$  is bounded and so the sequence $\bigl(\operatorname{Re}(z_n)\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has a convergent subsequence $\bigl(\operatorname{Re}(z_{n_k})\bigr)_{k\in\mathbb N}$, by the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem; let $x$ be its limit. By the same reason, the sequence $\bigl(\operatorname{Im}(z_{n_k})\bigr)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ has a convergent subsequence; let $y$ be its limit. But then $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has a subsequence which converges to $x+yi$. Since $\Omega$ is closed, $x+yi\in\Omega$.

Now, suppose that $\Omega$ is *not* compact. There are two possibilities:

1. $\Omega$ is not closed. Then take $z\in\overline\Omega\setminus\Omega$. Since $z\in\overline\Omega$, it is the limit of a sequence $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of elements of $\Omega$. Then every subsequence of $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $z$ and therefore no subsequence of $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to an element of $\Omega$.
2. $\Omega$ is unbounded. Then, for each $n\in\mathbb N$, take $z_n\in\Omega$ such that $\lvert z\rvert\geqslant n$. Then no subsequence of $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges and, in particular, no subsequence of $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to an element of $\Omega$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But doesn't this proof use information that is not in the textbook? Your proof claims that, if a set is bounded, then any sequence in that set is bounded, but the textbook does not say this. So do we need additional complex analysis knowledge (not from the textbook) to prove such a theorem? In other words, the textbook information is insufficient?

Comment: Asserting that a set $\Omega$ is bounded means that there is a $M>0$ such that $(\forall z\in\Omega):\lvert z\rvert<M$. So, if $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of elements of $\Omega$, then $(\forall n\in\mathbb N):\lvert z_n\rvert<M$, which is **exactly** what it means to assert that $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a bounded sequence.